# Why overrided target is forced by makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I NEED to call make by such way:

```
bin ?= bar                                                                      

all: ${bin}                                                                     

objects := 1.o 2.o                                                              

$(objects): %.o: ./%.cpp                                                        
▸   g++ -c  $< -o $@                                                            

foo: FORCE                                                                      
▸   bin=foo\                                                                    
▸   ▸   $(MAKE)·                                                                

${bin}: ${objects}                                                              
▸   g++  ${objects} -o ${bin}                                                  

FORCE:
```

i.e. default target is bar, but foo target call make again with bin=foo variable.
Problem is that when target foo is overrided (during second make call) it always run (linking)
This can be avoided if i use another target name:

```
foo_bla_bla: FORCE                                                                      
▸   bin=foo\                                                                    
▸   ▸   $(MAKE)
```

in this case foo file will be linked only when object files have chaned (right, that I need). But i need to use same name for this target to call
`make foo`
and get by this way foo bin.
So why overriding foo target entail forsed linking?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  What is *forced* linking, as opposed to (I guess) unforced?  What `make` commands are you executing from the command line, and how does their behavior differ from your expectation?  I do see some weirdness in the makefile presented, but I'm having trouble reconciling it with the description of `make`'s behavior.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, by "forced linking" i meant follow: tareget ${bin}: ${objects} ▸ g++ ${objects} -o ${bin} should run only then ${objects} have been changed, but in my case(make foo) link command(g++ ${objects} -o ${bin}) run every time, even if ${objects} have not been changed. make bar work right

Comment: I take you to mean that you want to avoid linking `foo` when it already exists and is newer than its constituent object files (otherwise, you'll need to explain more clearly what you mean by "if ${objects} have not been changed").  In that case, simply removing the rule for `foo` ought to achieve the desired result.  And that would be well, as it's unclear what benefit that you expect that rule to afford you.  If that's not a viable alternative in your real build system, then we need more information about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Solution, @MadScientist answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60005064/11733506

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not overriding the target by throwing away the complete information about the target.  You are overriding the *recipe* of the target: throwing away the old recipe and replacing it with the new one.  You will have received from make a warning about this (it would have been good to show this in your question).

The prerequisites of the target `foo` are still preserved, so the `FORCE` prerequisite from the first `foo` target is still there.  Thus, the `foo` target is always rebuilt.

This is not a great way to handle this.  A little bit better would be to check the value of `bin` and only define the recursive target if it's not `foo`:

```
ifneq ($(bin),foo)
foo: FORCE
▸   $(MAKE) bin=foo
endif
```

But even better than that is just to not use recursion at all.  Why do you need it?  Why not just say:

```
bar foo: ${objects}
▸   g++  ${objects} -o ${bin}
```

Comment: great, thank you! Yes i got warning about overriding, but i dont thing that it work so, override only recipe, now i get it. Why do i do so, this make build many files by pattern targets and i need to add some flags and libs and build another bin, so in order not to duplicate the pattern targets, I restart make with another enviroment variables. May be it is not  the simplest way